# Robolectric Testing: can not get the locale

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric, android-testing

I'm using robolectric framework to test my android project. It is working very well but i couldn't find how to solve the problem:

In my activity class, i have to take the current language as follows:

```
private void setCurrentLanguageChoosenInRadioGroup() {
    Configuration c = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
    String locale = c.locale.getLanguage();

    if(locale.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.DUTCH_LANGUAGE)){          
        radioLanguageGroup.check(dutchButton.getId());
    }
    else if(locale.equalsIgnoreCase(Locale.FRENCH.getLanguage())){
        radioLanguageGroup.check(frenchButton.getId());
    }
    else if(locale.equalsIgnoreCase(Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage())){
        radioLanguageGroup.check(englishButton.getId());
    }
}
```

But in the line of "c.locale.getLanguage();" i get nullpointerexception. It is my testing method:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    activity = new MainActivity();
    activity.onCreate(null); ....
```

Has anybody a idea what is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating robolectric to versions 2.x resolves the problem! In versions 0.9.x which is default version on their website, it is not applicable!

Thus, it can be adapted in this way:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("desired language/country");
Configuration c = new Configuration();
c.setLocale(loc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an NPE because the locale field is not being set. If you debug and put a breakpoint on the line after you instantiate the `Configuration` object notice the actual class that loaded. You will see that it is not `Configuration`, it is `ShadowConfiguration`.

You can view the source here: https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowConfiguration.java

I'm assuming (not having actually run your code) that `getResources().getConfiguration()` is either returning null, or doesn't have the locale set. There is a setLocale method in ShadowConfiguration that you could set in your test to manipulate the logic flow in your `setCurrentLanguageChoosenInRadioGroup()` method.

Comment: sorry for the late reaction. You are right, getResources().getConfiguration() is also null. after i see your answer, i have also tried to use ShadowConfiguration but probably it was not true way of use. I had just created a shadow object and initialized that. can you may be explain how it can be used? for example, in this case.